# Instatiate prefab Unity3D

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have 5 prefab as players options, have a "Change" button on my game menu where the user to click, change the character.

How do I make this choice in the "Menu" is applied when the game2d start?

Prefabs:

Bee, Bee1, Bee2, Bee3 and Bee4.

Bee (player) script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Bee : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;

    public Transform bee;
    private Animator animator;

    public bool isGrounded = true;
    public float force;

    public float jumpTime = 0.1f;
    public float jumpDelay = 0.1f;
    public bool jumped = false;
    public Transform ground;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        animator = bee.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        Move ();

    }


    void Move ()
    {

        isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast (this.transform.position, ground.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Floor"));
        animator.SetFloat ("runB", Mathf.Abs (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0) {

            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 0);
        }
        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0) {

            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0, 180);
        }

        if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown ("Vertical") && isGrounded && !jumped) {

            //  rigidbody2D.AddForce (transform.up * force);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (transform.up * force);
            jumpTime = jumpDelay;
            animator.SetTrigger ("jumpB");
            jumped = true;
        }

        jumpTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (jumpTime <= 0 && isGrounded && jumped) {

            animator.SetTrigger ("groundB");
            jumped = false;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the prefabs? E.g. if it's only varying in the visuals you should work with one single prefab and have a certain child of it hold the visuals (e.g. the sprite) and only change that.

Comment: @Gunnar B. Only change the sprite, the rest is the same!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Activating the one you need and deactivating all the rest should be enought:

[That tutorial can help you to do that](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/activating-gameobjects)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to move the visual part of the player into a child object, this is not required though. If you do, your root player object can just be an empty gameobject.

If you have scene changes you will need something that is persistent between scenes, e.g. a singleton with `DontDestroyOnLoad`. In any case this has to have information about all the possible sprites, e.g. in a list that you populate with `Resources.Load/LoadAll`. You can use this list to display the sprites in menu. Upon selection you save the index and on game start you just change the player sprite to the selected one with something like this (this would be in this class, e.g. called `GameController`):

```
playerGO.GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = spritesList[selected];
```

(This is assuming that the visuals are on a child object.)